# Doesn't show SVG

Tags: flutter

My flutter code doesn't show SVG.
I set `package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart` in `main.dart` and `flutter_svg: ^0.22.0` in dependencies. After that i run `flutter pug get`, and he doesn't show me error.

```
  final String wayMainLogo = 'assets/images/test.svg';
  .................................

               Row(
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      wayMainLogo,
                      height: 100,
                      semanticsLabel: 'Test',
                    ),
                    // Expanded(
                    //     flex: 1,
                    //     child: Container(
                    //         margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                    //         child: SvgPicture.asset(wayMainLogo))),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: if your asset path is ok, just restart your ide.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you

Add **svg** package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

Try below code

```
SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/abc.svg',//change your image on your need
     width: 20.0,
     height: 20.0,
  ),
```

Comment: I installed svg package, and this not resolve my problem.
Thats all package i have
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

Comment: what was the problem can you add your asstes folder and dependency code from pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Yes, I have registered all the paths in pabspec.yalm, thats no resolve my problem. My friend launch my code on mac, and it work allright. Im code on windows